# SVG element onclick gives ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: svg

I'm trying to add an onclick event to an svg element.

So I added a single onclick attribute to a specific element below. However it does not appear to be working.

I get the following errer: "Uncaught ReferenceError: clickCounty is not defined"

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
                function clickCounty(e)
                {
                    console.log("clickCounty");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <object data="custom.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

custom.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect onclick="clickCounty('test')" x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by literally including the SVG content / element in the markup.

When embedding it via the `<object>` tag it gave the reference errors. No idea why this occurs....

Answer (score 2):

You've two problems

a) the syntax of your script is wrong you have an extraneous `});` on its own line at the end

```
   <script>
            function clickCounty(e)
            {
                console.log("clickCounty");
            }
    </script>
```

b) you need window.top or window.parent to access methods defined in the html document from the svg document e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect onclick="window.parent.clickCounty('test')" x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" style="stroke:#006600; fill: #00cc00"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this, and working for me

```
 <svg ...
       (click)="testClick(point)"
 >
   ....
 </svg>
```